# How do i insert spaces between every letter in a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how I can insert spaces between every letter in a certain string. E.g. `test123` turns into `t e s t 1 2 3`, Does anyone know?

Comment: `string output = string.Join(" ", "test123".ToCharArray());` Or `"test123".AsEnumerable()`.

Comment: This worked, Thank you!

Comment: @Jimi: The first solution is not very efficient; do you see why?

Comment: Though `AsEnumerable` works, my preference here would instead be either `string.Join(' ', (IEnumerable<char>)whatever)` or `string.Join<char>(' ', whatever)`.  Do you see why these do the same thing?

Comment: @Eric Lippert  I'm more used to build strings like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441301/7444103). Here, it can be `var output = "test123".Aggregate(new StringBuilder(), (sb, c) => sb.Append(new[] { c, ' ' }));`. `string.Join()` has some difficulties joining chars (including the separator).

Comment: All of the above plus `Regex.Replace("test123", "(.)", "$1 ")`. No benchmarks and debatable readability, but it's nice of the language to provide multiple options.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As said in comments, simply do that:

`var result = string.Join(" ", "test123".ToCharArray());`

or, to avoid an unnecessary copy string made by ToCharArray:

`var result = string.Join<char>(" ", "test123");`

Comment: Though this works, it allocates an unnecessary extra copy of the string. Do you see how to make this work without allocating any extra memory other than the new string?

Comment: I don't understand why. Would you explain it, please?

Comment: Well, reason it out. **Why did you say `ToCharArray` in the first place**?

Comment: Just because of the method signature, I need an IEnumerable<char> or an  IEnumerable<string> to pass to it.

Comment: ok, if I use ```string.Join<char>(" ", "test123"); ``` I won't need to call ToCharArray who creates a string copy. Is that the point?

Answer (score -1):

Start at the end of the string and keep adding a white space as you work your way to the beginning. By working backwards, you don't need to worry about changing lengths or indices. https://dotnetfiddle.net/fC0yec

```
int i = str.Length-1;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
while(i > 0){
  sb.Insert(i, " ");
  i--;
}

string spacedOutStr = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: very inefficient