# C# Parse Date Variables from String (e.g. %today-4days%, %now+15min%)

Tags: c#, parsing, variables, datetime-format

I have a console application that I frequently need to pass variable DateTime's to.  I am currently using a switch to return the value when the variable matches the exact string and just add new ones as needed.  I would like to design it such that it is able to parse the variable and perform the correct operation based on the string.

Here are a few examples in the format I am currently using.

```
%today%
%today-5day%
%today-1sec%
%today+1month%
%now+15min%
%now-30sec%
%now+1week%
```

I also would like to parse variable such as

```
%lastmonday%
%nextfriday%
%monthstart%
%yearend%
```

etc. but those would seem to be best handled in the switch, and if unmatched passed to a function to parse and calculate the examples above.

I am not sure of the most elegant method to achieve this and was unable to find much in my searching.

Comment: You could build a markup-like *language* and parse the string contents based on the markup construct, [as show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441301/7444103). See the `Parse()` method combined with the `Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>>`  utility.

Comment: So basically your "placeholders" are the current DateTime (with or without the time component) an integer (positive for adding, negative for subtracting) and a unit of time. With the special case of just `%today%` (and probably `%now%`) which would work like `%today+0day%` for example. -- I'm no hero in terms of regular expressions, but something like `^%(today|now)([+-](\d*)(day|sec|month|min|week))?%$` should be able to parse all of your examples (and should be easy to adapt for more "units"). For most units there is already a `AddXXX` method on DateTime. Weeks would be `AddDays(x*7)`.

Comment: The other group of "placeholders" is _really_ special and yeah, mapping those to dedicated methods is probably the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try *regular expressions* in order to parse. First, let's extract a model: since commands are in format

```
Start (zero or more Modifiers)
```

E.g.

```
%today-5day+3hour%
```

where `today` is `Start` and `-5day` and `+3hour` are `Modifiers` we want two *models*

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...  

//TODO: add more starting points here
private static Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime>> s_Starts =
  new Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "now", () => DateTime.Now},
    { "today", () => DateTime.Today},
    { "yearend", () => new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 12, 31) },
};

//TODO: add more modifiers here 
private static Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, int, DateTime>> s_Modifiers =
  new Dictionary<string, Func<DateTime, int, DateTime>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "month", (source, x) => source.AddMonths(x)},
    { "week", (source, x) => source.AddDays(x * 7)},
    { "day", (source, x) => source.AddDays(x)},
    { "hour", (source, x) => source.AddHours(x)},
    { "min", (source, x) => source.AddMinutes(x)},
    { "sec", (source, x) => source.AddSeconds(x)},
};
```

Having a model (two dictionaries above) we can implement `MyParse` routine:

```
private static DateTime MyParse(string value) {
  if (null == value)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));

  var match = Regex.Match(value, 
    @"^%(?<start>[a-zA-Z]+)(?<modify>\s*[+-]\s*[0-9]+\s*[a-zA-Z]+)*%$");

  if (!match.Success)
    throw new FormatException("Invalid format");

  string start = match.Groups["start"].Value;

  DateTime result = s_Starts.TryGetValue(start, out var startFunc)
    ? startFunc()
    : throw new FormatException($"Start Date(Time) {start} is unknown.");

  var adds = Regex
    .Matches(match.Groups["modify"].Value, @"([+\-])\s*([0-9]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]+)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => (kind : m.Groups[3].Value, 
                amount : int.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value)));

  foreach (var (kind, amount) in adds) 
    if (s_Modifiers.TryGetValue(kind, out var func))
      result = func(result, amount);
    else
      throw new FormatException($"Modification {kind} is unknown.");

  return result;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  string[] tests = new string[] {
    "%today%",
    "%today-5day%",
    "%today-1sec%",
    "%today+1month%",
    "%now+15min%",
    "%now-30sec%",
    "%now+1week%",
  };

  string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
    .Select(test => $"{test,-15} :: {MyParse(test):dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss}")
  );

  Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:**

```
%today%         :: 07 05 2020 00:00:00
%today-5day%    :: 02 05 2020 00:00:00
%today-1sec%    :: 06 05 2020 23:59:59
%today+1month%  :: 07 06 2020 00:00:00
%now+15min%     :: 07 05 2020 18:34:55
%now-30sec%     :: 07 05 2020 18:19:25
%now+1week%     :: 14 05 2020 18:19:55
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a small example of parsing a string that has today and day in it (using the example of %today-5day%).

Note: this will only work if the value passed in for the added days is between 0-9, to handle large numbers you will have to loop over the result of the string.

You can follow this code block to parse other results as well.

```
            switch (date)
            {
                case var a when a.Contains("day") && a.Contains("today"):
                    return DateTime.Today.AddDays(char.GetNumericValue(date[date.Length - 5]));
                default:
                    return DateTime.Today;
            }
```

Comment: There are also many other methods to handle what you need (.AddMonths, .AddHours, etc.)