# How to parse string and prepare it for math

Tags: c#

I want to parse latex string to math expression with following code

```
static string ParseString(List<string> startItems, string input)
{
    foreach (var item in startItems)
    {
        int charLocation = input.IndexOf(item, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (charLocation > 0)
        {
            switch (input.Substring(0, charLocation).Last())
            {
                case '{':
                case '+':
                case '-':
                case '*':
                    break;
                default: 
                    input = input.Replace(item, "*" + item); 
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return input;
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ToParse = @"\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}*4\sqrt{3}";
    ToParse = ParseString(new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { @"\frac", @"\sqrt" }, ToParse);
    Console.WriteLine(ToParse);
}
```

I should get before every \sqrt word multiply char.But my program breaks in first \sqrt and cant parse others.
Result is

```
\sqrt{3}\sqrt{3}*4\sqrt{3}
```

And i want to get

```
\sqrt{3}*\sqrt{3}*4*\sqrt{3}
```

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: Can you add resulting string please?

Comment: @GuruStron done

Comment: I mean what you want to get.

Comment: Ok done now, sorry

Comment: A Formula Parser or solver is far from trivial. It is one of those things, where you are best of just using somebody elses code. I never needed one, so I can not give you advice.

Comment: yes parser will be help but i try my own things

Comment: See the combination of a simple Regex parser + `Dictionary<string, Func<string, string>` [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59441301/7444103).

Comment: and one more [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7377402/2501279)

Comment: @GuruStron i expected more rational solution

Comment: @JamesJohnson what do you mean by "rational"?

Answer (score 0):

Based on provided example you can do as simple as `input = input.Replace(item, "*" + item).TrimStart('*');` (`Replace` replaces all occurrences of string/char).

As for your code, you have next issues:

- First inclusion of `\sqrt` returns `charLocation` set to 0 (arrays are xero-based in C#), so your check `charLocation > 0` evaluates to *false*, so nothing happens
- `input.Substring(i, l)` accepts 2 parameters - start index and **length**, so it is incorrect to use your `charLocation` as second parameter(even if you remove previous check, `input.Substring(0, charLocation).Last()` will end in exception `Sequence contains no elements`).

So if you want to go through all occurrences and insert symbol based on some logic then you'll need to have some cycle and move start index and calculate length(and also use something else, not `Replace`). Or you can dive into [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: ye regex will be help